# Export multiple lists into a single CSV file

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, jquery, jsom, large-lists

I have a requirement to fetch 2 large lists and merge data into a single CSV file. Suppose Lists are as below :

**List A**

- Column1
- Data1
- Data2

**List B**

- Column2
- Data3
- Data4

Then Data should be displayed in csv file as below :

- Column1 Column2
- Data1    Data3
- Data2    Data4

Is there any way to achieve this using REST/JSOM ?

Please note that as per the requirement we want to do it multiple times so there should not be any manual work to do.

Answer (score 1):

This could easily be done via PowerShell. Check out the [get-pnplistitem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps) cmdlet, in conjunction with the [export-csv](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6) cmdlet.

Comment: This does not help me, we need a script in JSOM/REST to perform this as mentioned in the question clearly.

Comment: There is a pnp js library as well. Here is a page with samples: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Basic--Operations. Once you have the data, you can generate a csv: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side

Comment: Thanks for the references Mike but I am very much struggling to fulfill this and references of complete raw data are not helping me here. If possible please post a sample code so I can modify that and use.

Comment: That's why i orginally posted the powershell, it's the simplest way. If you need the javascript route, you'll need a way to get js on the page. In a modern page, that means either SPFx, or the modern script editor web part, which is an open source part available here: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor  - Once you are able to get script on the page, you'd need to reference the pnp js. Once that's done, then the rest shouldnt be too bad, as the above links have samples.

Comment: I am working on classic experience so that is not a problem. I will look into PnP libraries and will update here.

Comment: Ah, so just a content editor web part will do, which is simpler. Here are the docs, scroll down to the section titled "from a content editor web part": https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Install-and-Use

Comment: Requirement was changed a bit so I have asked in a new question. Check my progress from https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/258130/merge-two-list-and-export-the-report-to-excel